# how to add ASPNETDB.MDF database to generate crystal reports

Tags: asp.net, crystal-reports

I have the connection string like this:

> connectionString="Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\ASPNETDB.MDF;Integrated Security=True;User Instance=True" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"

How do I give the new data source connection to this ASPNETDB.MDF (the database created with asp.net userlogin) file??

When I give the .\SQLEXPRESS as data source it shows me some other database file but not this database??

How can I connect this for crystal reports?

Comment: Is this connection string an ODBC connection, or a connection string in your application?  What version of Crystal Reports are you using?

Answer (score 1):

Asp.net membership provider is a new feature of Asp.net 2005. We can create membership tables using aspnet_regsql.exe in vs command prompt. This blog describes how to create aspnetdb databse in your Sqlexpress

ASP.NET Membership

ASP.NET membership is a built in way to validate and store user credentials.And Asp.Net membership helps in user authentication in websites. We can implememt membershipprovider by Asp.net Forms authentication and Login control.

Purppose Of Membeship provider

1. Create new user with username and password.
2. Storing membership information in Sql Server,Active directory etc.

3.Authentication of users. By using ASP.NET login control,ASp.NET usercreation wizard etc implement complete authentication system.

4.Fascilitate role management etc

The database used to access membership database is normaly created with name ASPNETDB.MDF. Here is how to install ASPNETDB database

Creating ASPNETDB DATABASE in your SQLEXPRESS
ASPNETDB.MDF is membership provider database and is used for storing and retrieving
membership data from database and here we are going to see how to create membership provider database . The command used to create Aspnetdb.mdf is ASPNET_RegSQL.EXE

1.Start->Programs->Microsoft visual studio 2005->visual studio tools->Visual Studio 2005 command prompt. Type ASPNET_RegSQL.EXE in the visual Studio 2005 command prompt

1. A wizard with the heading ” Welcome To The Asp.Net Sql Server Wizard ” will be displayed. Here need to click Next
2. Next a wizard with ” Select Setup Option ” will displayed. Now we need to select setup option “Configure sql server for application purpose is default”. Select which one you wants and next.
3. A window with ” Select Sql Server Database ” Will be shown Now we need to select our sql server database. Here needs to set server, authentication type and database.
   If select the default name”aspnetDb.mdf” will be selected. If you wants to modify existing database select that database.

5.Now A confirm will be displayed with heading “Confirm your Settings”. Now check servername and database name and click next.

1. A window with ” The database Has Been Created Or Modified ” Will displayed. Now click Finish

These all are how to create an asp.net membership database on sql Server 2005 database